# xpages run agent as signer

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

There are many ways to run legacy LS code on an xpages, including the new webquerysaveagent property against a datasource in 8.5.3. But I am not sure how I can run an agent as signer (so the run as web user is unticked) without re-writing the whole code in SSJS. Has anyone figured out how this can be achieved?

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with *sessionAsSigner* - method:

```
sessionAsSigner.getCurrentDatabase().getAgent("RunAsSigner").run()
```

The option "Run as webuser" has to be disabled.

To run with the datasource you have to use the corresponding *NotesDocument*:

```
sessionAsSigner.getCurrentDatabase().getAgent("RunAsSigner").runWithDocumentContext(document1.getDocument())
```

Comment: Will give this a go - thank you Sven. Most places on-line mention that this is not possible, so wasn't sure if this would work!